# is not a valid entity or mapped class Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine with Codeigniter. So i write a library class for using them together. But i cant access entities (after creating them from db with reverse-engineering). Doctrine gives error: **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class Actions is not a valid entity or mapped super class.'**

I just add this code for this situation to library class and works everything right but **speed is very low**:

```
    $this->em->getConfiguration()
             ->setMetadataDriverImpl(
                new DatabaseDriver(
                        $this->em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
                )
    );
```

What can i do for this error? I generated entities from DB with this function:

```
    $cmf = new DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
    $cmf->setEntityManager($this->em);
    $metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();
    $generator = new EntityGenerator();

    $generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
    $generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
    $generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
    $generator->generate($metadata, APPPATH."models/entities");
```

My Action entity:

```
<?php



/**
 * Actions
 *
 * @Table(name="actions")
 * @Entity
 */
class Actions
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var string $nameSafe
     *
     * @Column(name="name_safe", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    public $nameSafe;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string $name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set nameSafe
     *
     * @param string $nameSafe
     */
    public function setNameSafe($nameSafe)
    {
        $this->nameSafe = $nameSafe;
    }

    /**
     * Get nameSafe
     *
     * @return string $nameSafe
     */
    public function getNameSafe()
    {
        return $this->nameSafe;
    }
}
```

(edit) My Library Code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache,
    Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory,
    Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator;

    /**
     * CodeIgniter Doctrine Class
     *
     * initializes basic doctrine settings and act as doctrine object
     *
     * @author  Mehmet Aydın Bahadır
     * @link    http://www.biberltd.com/
     */
    class Doctrine {

          /**
           * @var EntityManager $em
           */
            public $em = null;

          /**
           * constructor
           */
          public function __construct()
          {
            // load database configuration from CodeIgniter
            require APPPATH.'config/database.php';

            // Set up class loading. You could use different autoloaders, provided by your favorite framework,
            // if you want to.
            require_once APPPATH.'third_party/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

            $doctrineClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine',  APPPATH.'third_party');
            $doctrineClassLoader->register();
            $entitiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('models', rtrim(APPPATH, "/" ));
            $entitiesClassLoader->register();
            $proxiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('proxies', APPPATH.'models');
            $proxiesClassLoader->register();

            // Set up caches
            $config = new Configuration;
            $cache = new ArrayCache;
            $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
            $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(APPPATH.'models/entities'));
            $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
            $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

            // Proxy configuration
            $config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'models/proxies');
            $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

            // Set up logger
            //$logger = new EchoSQLLogger;
            //$config->setSQLLogger($logger);

            $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses( TRUE );
            // Database connection information
            $connectionOptions = array(
                'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
                'user' =>     $db['default']['username'],
                'password' => $db['default']['password'],
                'host' =>     $db['default']['hostname'],
                'dbname' =>   $db['default']['database']
            );

            // Create EntityManager
            $this->em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
//          $this->generate_classes();

          }

          /**
           * generate entity objects automatically from mysql db tables
           * @return none
           */
          public function generate_classes(){     

//            $this->em->getConfiguration()
//                     ->setMetadataDriverImpl(
//                        new DatabaseDriver(
//                                $this->em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
//                        )
//            );

            $cmf = new DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
            $cmf->setEntityManager($this->em);
            $metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();
            $generator = new EntityGenerator();

            $generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
            $generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
            $generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
            $generator->generate($metadata, APPPATH."models/entities");

          }

    }
?>
```

Comment: So you removed something because it was slow, and now you ask why it doesn't work ? :-) You need cache your meta data.

Comment: is this dont cache my metadata?             $cache = new ArrayCache;
            $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);

Comment: use ApcCache if you have APC installed (you should, if you care about performance)

Comment: how can i install APC Cache for Doctrine?

Comment: Install PHP's APC extension. After that, replace ArrayCache by ApcCache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is editing php.ini file for closing eAccelerator:

```
eaccelerator.enable="0"
```

Comment: MAB please can you help me out. Actually i do all things which you mention in answer and comment but still stuck in same problem.